# How can i extract code related to files for each commit in github?

Tags: git, github

I need code for each file for each commit for my research work. How can I get it?

I know using git clone we can get the code related to the final version. But to study for my research i need file level details for each commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout a specific version of the code using

```
git checkout <commit-hash>
```

You can obtain `<commit-hash>` through use of `git log` or `gitk`.

Comment: Can i get like getting just the actual code for a list of commits and then storing each of the code (per commit) in different folder.